# Validating TextBox on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-ui

I have textbox and i want to replace the value % of textbox with - on form submit using jquery. But not getting how can i do it.

Here is my HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="form" id="form" (submit)="addDetails();form.reset()" class="form-style-9" ngNativeValidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label for="username">User Name</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" id="username" class="form-control"
                placeholder="Please Enter User Name" formControlName="username" required="true">

            </div>
            <input type="hidden" id="usernameX" name="username" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

JS

```
var doReplace = function(string){
    return string.replace(/%/g, "-");
}
var $usernameX = $('#usernameX');
$("#form").on("submit", function(e) {
$usernameX.val(doReplace($('#username').val()));
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged Angular? Angular and jQuery are worlds apart!

Comment: Becaus i have used angular and jquery both. And if i am not wrong we can use it together.

Comment: While it's possible to use jQuery and Angular together, you really shouldn't.

Comment: ^^^ This. You really shouldn't use jQuery with Angular. Angular maintains control of the DOM, once you bring jQuery in, you're outside of the Angular context, and things can go terribly wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this. But you **don't need jQuery for this**:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" id="form" (submit)="onSubmit()" class="form-style-9" ngNativeValidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label for="username">User Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Please Enter User Name" formControlName="username"
        required="true">

    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="usernameX" name="username" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And add a `onSubmit()` to the component.ts:

```
public onSubmit(): void {
 this.addDetails();
 const value = this.form.get('username').value.replace(new RegExp('%'), '-');'
 this.form.reset();
}
```

Comment: Its not replacing.

Comment: on debug it shows replaced but on submit its not replacing.

Comment: Put a console log after replacing the value and see.  How are you getting values from the form to submit?

Comment: it replaces just one % what if i have  %%

Comment: Use a regex expression for that. You can test your regex expression in [here](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: Worked. Thank you so much .

Comment: Please mark the answer as the correct one if your are satisfied with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var myStr = 'replace_underscore_by_minus';
    var newStr = myStr.replace(/_/g, "-");
```